# Struct not changing with Binding

Tags: swiftui

I have this struct

```
struct MyObject {
  var name:String
  var color:String
  var date:Date

init(name:String = "", color: String = "", date:Date = Date()) {
  self.name = name
  self.color = color
  self.date = date
}
```

Then I have this on `ContentView`

```
@State private var temporaryObject = MyObject()
```

I send this to a view, like

```
var body: some View {
  DoSomething($temporaryObject)
}
```

This is `DoSomething`

```
struct DoSomething: View {
  @Binding var temporaryObject:MyObject

  init(_ temporaryObject:Binding<MyObject>) {
    self._temporaryObject = temporaryObject
  }

  var body: some View {
    Button(action: {

     // here is the problem
     temporaryObject.name = "kkkk"
     print(temporaryObject.name) // is equal to ""

     }, label: {
        Text("click me")
     })
```

When I click the button, `temporaryObject.name`, in theory, is changed to "kkkk" but the print line shows it is still equals to empty.

why?

Comment: With the above code you will get an error at this line `DoSomething(temporaryObject)`, because you are not passing binding using `$`

Comment: Your code doesn't compile for several reasons.

Comment: @NiravD, just a typo here. Sorry.

Comment: Is your `DoSomething` code a copy paste from your project? The `init` and the `@Binding var` should be inside the `struct` declaration. Right now this code seems incorrect. Please can you make sure the code in your question is correct.

Comment: Yes, the code as it is here is how I have typed it on my project. My original typing had some codes here but I have fixed it now".

Comment: see now........

Comment: The code is supposed to work. Consider that `print` shows the result only in the simulator.  You can even delete the `init` method.

Comment: strangely, it does not work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this example code works well for me. Does this code (taken from your question) not work for you?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var temporaryObject = MyObject()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            DoSomething(temporaryObject: $temporaryObject)
            Text(temporaryObject.name)  // <-- for testing
        }
    }
}

struct MyObject {
    var name:String
    var color:String
    var date:Date
    
    init(name:String = "", color: String = "", date:Date = Date()) {
        self.name = name
        self.color = color
        self.date = date
    }
}

struct DoSomething: View {
    @Binding var temporaryObject:MyObject

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            temporaryObject.name = "kkkk"
            print(temporaryObject.name) // is equal to "kkkk"
        }, label: {
            Text("click me")
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: No I see an error but if I create a blank project, it works. The good and old xcode. Thanks